# How to show folders in windows command which start with dot?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

1. my OS is windows 7;
2. the folders start with dot(.) are hidden folders;
3. there are several sub-folders which like .android, .cache, etc in my target folder.
4. what I want is to find all of the folders and then remove them and also its contents.
5. what I did was running follow command in a cmd file, but seems not working properly at all:

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%targetfolder%\\.android" /s /b /a') do (echo "%%i" && rd /s /q "%%i")
   for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%targetfolder%\\.cache" /s /b /a') do (echo "%%i" && rd /s /q "%%i")
   ```

Anyone has any solutions?

Comment: Looking at the information under `Dir /?` I would assume that if you're looking for `D`irectories which are `H`idden, you'd need to at least use, `('Dir /B/S/ADH "%targetfolder%\.*" 2^>Nul')`, after first making sure that `%targetfolder%` is both defined and exists.

Comment: names starting with dot are not hidden in Windows. They're hidden just because they have the hidden bits set. uncheck it and those will be visible without any name changes

Comment: Thanks for adding comments,
additional:
1.Yes, I'm looking for a folder with name start with dot(.) whether is hidden or not;
2.add the parameter /a, the folder could be found, but once the name start with dot(.). it show only the sub-folders but ignore itself. So that the RD command could not remove it successfully, this is the reason for the questions.

Answer (score 0):

I built the example below and it worked in all my tests.  The only condition that cause it to fail is targetting a parent directory to the batch file, since it couldn't delete something that a working process was currently executing from.

Using 'pushd' solved for that condition.  And in any normal use, 'popd' will return the working directory to the original location.

## Put Inside A Batch File:

```
@echo off
rem setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set zDebug=0

if %zDebug% NEQ 0 echo ;[i] Execution started from {%cd%}

for %%A in ("c:\temp","c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff","c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android","c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\DoNotDeleteThis","c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\DoNotDeleteThis\.OkDeleteThis","c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android\Dir1","c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android\Dir2","c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android\Dir3","c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android\Dir3\.TriggerAlreadyDeletedClause") do (
    if exist "%%~A" (
        if %zDebug% NEQ 0 (echo ;[i] Directory Already Exists {"%%~A"})
    ) else (
        mkdir "%%~A" && (if %zDebug% NEQ 0 echo ;[i] Directory Created {"%%~A"})
    )
)

set "targetfolder=c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff"

if %zDebug% NEQ 0 echo ;[i] Changing Dir To Begin Removing .Directories {%targetfolder%}

pushd "%targetfolder%" 2>nul && (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /s /ad ".*"') do (
        if exist "%%~A" (
            rd /s /q "%%~A" >nul 2>&1 && (echo ;[i] Deleted {"%%~A"}) || (echo ;[e] Failed To Delete {"%%~A"})
        ) else (
            echo ;[i] Already Deleted {"%%~A"}
        )
    )
) || (
    echo ;[e] Failed To Change Directory To Target Folder {%targetfolder%}
)

goto :zEOF

:zExitEarly
echo ;[i] Exiting Early...

:zEOF
popd >nul 2>&1 || echo ;[i] Starting Directory No Longer Exists
exit /b
```

## Output when "zDebug=1"

```
;[i] Execution started from {C:\}
;[i] Directory Already Exists {"c:\temp"}
;[i] Directory Already Exists {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff"}
;[i] Directory Created {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android"}
;[i] Directory Already Exists {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\DoNotDeleteThis"}
;[i] Directory Created {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\DoNotDeleteThis\.OkDeleteThis"}
;[i] Directory Created {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android\Dir1"}
;[i] Directory Created {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android\Dir2"}
;[i] Directory Created {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android\Dir3"}
;[i] Directory Created {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android\Dir3\.TriggerAlreadyDeletedClause"}
;[i] Changing Dir To Begin Removing .Directories {c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff}
;[i] Deleted {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android"}
;[i] Already Deleted {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android\Dir3\.TriggerAlreadyDeletedClause"}
;[i] Deleted {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\DoNotDeleteThis\.OkDeleteThis"}
```

## Output when "zDebug=0"

```
;[i] Deleted {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android"}
;[i] Already Deleted {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\.Android\Dir3\.TriggerAlreadyDeletedClause"}
;[i] Deleted {"c:\temp\zTest-DeleteStuff\DoNotDeleteThis\.OkDeleteThis"}
```